# How to auto configure a controller before handler mappings are registered?

Tags: spring-boot

I am creating a custom auto-configuration module and it has a custom error controller which implements `ErrorController`. I need my customErrorController instance instantiated before `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping#initHandlerMethods` for reasons (I think) is not relevant here.

I've tried `@AutoConfigureBefore({WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})` with no luck, it still *sometimes* hits `initHandlerMethods` before my controller is instantiated.

What should I put in `@AutoConfigureBefore`, any clues?

Comment: I think it may be ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration. Spring Lemon does the same, and here is the code: https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/LemonAutoConfiguration.java#L84

Comment: actually I did try this `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class` too to no avail. I will edit question to reflect that as well.